# Narrow the field Buttons Adding

Tags: powerbi

I create a hierarchy matrix table but can't figure it out where "narrow the field" buttons are.

Recent view:
[image]

and how I'd like to see is like this:

[image]

How can i Turn on/off those buttons?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your first question is:-

To adjust the column width you can follow below steps:

1. Put your cursor on the line between both column
2. Press your mouse key and move width of column according to your requirement

Solution to your second question is:-

You can turn on/off **+/- icons**  properties so those button will display if its **on** or will not display if it **off**

[image]

Comment: +/- icons, that's what i was looking for. couldn't see where it was.  It was in "Row Headers"